# Moveit constraint to look at a point

Tags: ros2, moveit, motion-planning

Using Moveit under ROS2 (humble), I am trying to have a robot manipulator point the end-effector (technically a camera attached to it) at a point in space. With the different options for constrained planning, I expected the `VisibilityConstraint` to allow this, but its [documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/moveit_msgs/html/msg/VisibilityConstraint.html) explicitely states the opposite:

> The constraint is useful to maintain visibility to a disc (the target) in a particular frame.
> This disc forms the base of a visibiliy cone whose tip is at the origin of the sensor.
> Maintaining visibility is done by ensuring the robot does not obstruct the visibility cone.
>
> Note:
> This constraint does NOT enforce minimum or maximum distances between the sensor
> and the target, nor does it enforce the target to be in the field of view of
> the sensor. A PositionConstraint can (and probably should) be used for such purposes.

My goal is exactly the situation mentioned (EDIT: labeled as "not enforced") in the note. However, I don't understand how a [PositionConstraint](https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/moveit_msgs/html/msg/PositionConstraint.html) can be used for that, as it only seems to constrain the position of a given link to a certain region of space. Likewise, an [OrientationConstraint](https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/moveit_msgs/html/msg/OrientationConstraint.html) allows to set the orientation of a given link, but any orientation will only be correct for a specific position.

I found [a similar question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/83076/moveit-look-at-point-at-while-moving/83077#83077) which suggested using the [bio_ik](https://github.com/TAMS-Group/bio_ik) kinematics solver instead of the default one as it provides a `LookAtGoal`. However, the instructions are for ROS 1, and since the `VisibilityConstraint` documentation mentions that this should be acheivable with a `PositionConstraint`, I am curious as to how.

In summary:

- I want to point the z axis of my robot's end-effector towards a given target point $t$
- If I have a specific position $p$ I want for the end-effector, I can compute an orientation that aligns the z axis with the $t-p$ vector
- In theory (I haven't got it working yet), I can use an `OrientationConstraint` to also relax the rotation around the z axis of the effector (since it is irrelevant in my case)
- I could also constrain the position of the end-effector to a line along the $t-p$ vector with a `PositionConstraint`
- However, if the position of the end-effector is a larger region of space, I don't understand how to also constrain the orientation such that the end-effector will point at my target

As an alternative, I suppose I could plan the motion to get the end-effector in the appropriate area (using only a `PositionConstraint`) and *then* rotate it such that it points at the target. However, this may not be possible for all positions within the region. I would also like the end-effector to be pointed at the target throughout the motion.

Many Thanks!

Comment: On the one hand you say "VisibilityConstraint to allow this, but its documentation explicitely states the opposite:". But on the other hand you say "My goal is exactly the situation mentioned in the note." So at the end you seem to affirm that the visibility constraints are your solution.

Comment: To clarify (I've edited the text), the goal is the situation that the note mentions is "not enforced", i.e., I want the target to be in the field of view of the sensor at all times